# Microsoft CognitiveServices Speech Audio not working

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services

Used the following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/cognitive-services-apis-create-account?tabs=singleservice%2Cunix

to Create a Cognitive Services resource.

Then used:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-speech-to-text?tabs=windowsinstall&pivots=programming-language-csharp

to get the code example to recognize from a microphone.

Included the Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio as NuGetPackae and everything worked fine on windows 10 with vs 2019.
Pushed the project up to GitHub and downloaded it onto my macBook and nothing is happening....No errors....nothing in call stack nothing...(apart from a message in the threads about cancelation token? but im not sure if this is an error or not??..when I say nothing is happening..the code runs and displays "Speak into your microphone" in the terminal...then after one second it closes and program ends

Does anyone know why it isnt working or what I can do to further test it. thanks
also to note microphone is working on macbook, have tested this, thanks

[image]

**UPDATE**
Have followed the instructions from:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/quickstart/csharp/dotnetcore/from-microphone

and still not working...

the problem is (please see two below images)

```
var result = await recognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync();
```

result.Text is returning "Hello how are you" in windows 10 with VS 2019,
however in BigSur 11.6 macbook with VS 2019 8.10.11 (build 8) it is returning "" does anyone know why? I cant understand why ios is returning 'NoMatch"
[image]

[image]

Comment: In 1.19.0 we have changed to xcframework. Are you using existing project with Speech SDK and when you moved to the latest Speech SDK, you are seeing this error ?

Comment: Hi Ram, thanks for the reply. Yes existing project is using Microsoft.cognitiveServices.Speech SDK, currently installed
version 1.18.0. Everything works in VS 2019, with Windows 10 for android. However, in macbook it returns empty string " " in result.Text (please see update of OP)
For purpose of testing what you said I have upgraded the Speech SDK NuGet package on the IOS to 1.19.0 and still not working. No the problem is there from the beginning on macbook 1.18 and 1.19. (it was never working) do you know why text is returning "" in ios?

Comment: Hey Guys...wasn't able to get any further with this would appreciate some help if anyone has the time to help me investigate. Ive added a bounty...hopefully someone can help. thanks

Comment: On mac, try: var noMatchDetails = Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.NoMatchDetails.FromResult(result); for further information

Comment: Also the duration does not include trailing or leading silence, on mac you have 5 seconds of audio and on windows only 2. You should save the AudioConfig.FromDefaultMicrophoneInput() and play it in a mediaplayer.